# Non-slanted (siunitx style) unit prefixes with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx

I've taken the example from the `pgfplots` manual on `Preset SI prefixes` and modified it slightly, changing a prefix from `milli` to `micro`.

The result is that the units of the yaxis are stated as micro-Newton, a `\mu` and a capital N. The `\mu` is slanted here, which is what disturbs and surprises me. The `siunitx` package (which I use everywhere else) would set the unit with an upright `\mu`. That's what I'd like to happen here as well.

Here's a rendering of this sample document:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[change x base,
    x SI prefix=kilo,x unit=m,
    y SI prefix=micro,y unit=N,
    xlabel=Distance,ylabel=Force (\si{\micro\newton})]
    \addplot coordinates {
    (1000,1)
    (2000,1.1)
    (3000,1.2)
    (4000,1.3)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I thought I had found a solution for this when I came across the line

```
\pgfplotsset{unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}}
```

in the `pgfplots` manual, but this does not help because the `micro` is passed to `siunitx` as `\mu` rather than `\micro`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in `tikzlibrarypgfplots.units.code.tex`. Take a look at lines 109-180, where the prefixes are defined. You'll find (for `micro` only):

```
/pgfplots/x SI prefix/micro/.style={/pgfplots/axis base prefix={axis x base 6 prefix \mu}},%
/pgfplots/y SI prefix/micro/.style={/pgfplots/axis base prefix={axis y base 6 prefix \mu}},%
/pgfplots/z SI prefix/micro/.style={/pgfplots/axis base prefix={axis z base 6 prefix \mu}},%
```

This is what causes `\mu` to be passed even when using

```
\pgfplotsset{unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}}
```

as you mentioned. I'm not sure the best way to solve this in the general case (where the user is not guaranteed to be using `siunitx`), but here is a workaround for your case:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}
\pgfplotsset{
  x SI prefix/micro/.style={/pgfplots/axis base prefix={axis x base 6 prefix \micro}},
  y SI prefix/micro/.style={/pgfplots/axis base prefix={axis y base 6 prefix \micro}},
  z SI prefix/micro/.style={/pgfplots/axis base prefix={axis z base 6 prefix \micro}},
  unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}},
}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[change x base,
    x SI prefix=kilo,x unit=\metre,
    y SI prefix=micro,y unit=\newton,
    xlabel=Distance,ylabel=Force (\si{\micro\newton})]
    \addplot coordinates {
    (1000,1)
    (2000,1.1)
    (3000,1.2)
    (4000,1.3)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### More detailed discussion

The rest of the prefix lines also leave something to be desired when `siunitx` is being used. Here's a typical example:

```
/pgfplots/x SI prefix/yocto/.style={/pgfplots/axis base prefix={axis x base 24 prefix y}},%
```

This does not follow the `siunitx` convention of using the literal prefix as a `csname`. If we were to do that, the typical line would look like:

```
/pgfplots/x SI prefix/yocto/.style={/pgfplots/axis base prefix={axis x base 24 prefix \yocto}},%
```

but, of course, this would only work with

```
\pgfplotsset{unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}}
```

just as my workaround above. The ideal solution would involve significant modifications to the code, but perhaps an `siunitx` option could be considered (*a la* `circuitikz`), which resets all prefixes to the literal prefix as a `csname`, and automatically sets up `unit code` for usage with `siunitx`.

To fix this when `siunitx` is not being used requires yet more modifications because of the default setup of `unit code`, which is entirely in math mode. Even if upright greeks were available, using them as part of the `axis base prefix` key is not allowed because we're not in text mode at that point.

Comment: Correct! :) I just posted that :) However it is not a bug, if you do not use `siunitx` changing to `\micro` would not compile (try leaving out `unit code/.code`).

Comment: It _is_ a bug, because units should be typeset upright, and by default for `micro` they are not. I'm adding some more notes to my answer now; a general solution would require loading some package for upright greeks.

Comment: Yes, but ultimately it requires a package for the upright greek. Forcing the user to load it is not the best way around. Agreed there should be a switch to handle the `micro` command in a generic way.

Comment: +1, you have already nailed it. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: You can also set `y unit=\si{\micro\newton}`. Could be that this was just added recently though.